# # operator in bash to get the length of a string literal

Tags: string, bash, path, parameter-expansion

I'm having trouble getting the length of a plain string in bash using `#` (is there a common name for this operator? The reference manual calls it a special parameter, but there are many of those). More specifically, I want to get the length of a path with `:` as a delimiter.

I've tried a few things, following the `${#parameter}` syntax found in the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), but they all return an error.

```
length=${#":/path/to/a/directory"} # "bad substitution"
length=${#':/path/to/a/directory'} # "bad substitution"
length=${#:/path/to/a/directory} # "syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/path/to/a/directory")"

# Removing the `:`
length=${#"/path/to/a/directory"} # "bad substitution"
length=${#'/path/to/a/directory'} # "bad substitution"
length=${#/path/to/a/directory} # `length` is set to 0
```

Clearly, using a variable works.

```
var=":/path/to/a/directory"
length=${#var} # `length` is correctly set to 21
```

It seems evident that `bash` does not support using `#` on a literal string, but could there be a workaround to using a variable?

Comment: Would you consider "using `zsh`" to be a workaround? In that shell, `length=${#:-...}` does what you want.

Comment: However, there's little need to compute the length of an explicit string, since you can always count the characters yourself and hard-code the value of `length`. The operator exists for variables because you may not know the length of the variable value before hand.

Comment: Calling `#` it an *operator* gives the wrong idea.  It appears (with the semantics you have in mind) only in the context of parameter expansion, which is what the `${}` signifies, or as a shell parameter itself.  It is a feature or option provided by parameter expansion.  Having couched it in those terms, it should be less surprising that you cannot use that feature except in conjunction with a parameter (including, but not limited to, a shell variable).

Answer (score 2):

> could there be a workaround to using a variable?

No, there is no workaround. Any *variable* expansions, like `${#`, work with *variables*, not strings.

> is there a common name for this operator?

No, I do not think so. I call it "length operator" in my head. It would be really nice to have names for all those different expansions, they all are nameless.

---

> ```
>  length=${#/path/to/a/directory} # `length` is set to 0
> ```

The `$#` variable is the special variable expanding to the number of arguments passed to a script. In the case of your shell, `$#` is 0, your shell was invoked with no parameters. The `${#/path/to/a/directory}` is parsed as `${parameter/pattern/string}` case, where the parts are `parameter=#`, `pattern="path"` and `string="to/a/directory"`.

Comment: Bummer, but makes sense, after all the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameters) defines a _parameter_ (from _parameter expansion_) as "an entity that stores values".

Answer (score 1):

`${...}` is only for expanding variables, and performing transformations on the variable value in the process. So it can't be used for other expressions.

However, you can get the string length using command substitution.

```
length=$(printf "%s" ":/path/to/a/directory" | wc -c)
```

`printf` is needed to avoid appending a newline to the string before piping to `wc`, as it would count that character.

Comment: Good catch. I've replaced it with `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

`${#...}` is only for variables but with a literal string you can always do any of these (or various similar alternatives):

```
$ expr length ':/path/to/a/directory'
21

$ expr ':/path/to/a/directory' : '.*'
21

$ wc -c < <(printf '%s' ':/path/to/a/directory')
21

$ printf '%s' ':/path/to/a/directory' | wc -c
21
```

You can save the result of either command in a variable in the usual way, e.g.:

```
$ length=$( expr length ':/path/to/a/directory' )
$ echo "$length"
21
```

The only one above that's kinda cryptic IMO is `expr ':/path/to/a/directory' : '.*'` - that's using `expr`'s `:` operator to compare the original string `':/path/to/a/directory'` to the regex `'.*'`, which of course matches the whole of that string, and then printing the number of characters that match, i.e. the number of characters in the original string.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a function to do what you want.  This [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean pure Bash code demonstrates one way to do it:

```
# Assign the length of parameter 2 to the variable named by parameter 1
function set_to_length
{
    # Check parameter 1 is a valid variable name and parameter 2 is defined
    [[ -z ${1-} ]]              && return 1
    [[ $1 == *[^[:alnum:]_]* ]] && return 1
    [[ $1 == [[:digit:]]* ]]    && return 1
    [[ -z ${2+_} ]]             && return 1

    printf -v "$1" '%s' "${#2}"
}
```

- For example, running `set_to_length var :/path/to/a/directory` gives `var` the value `21`.
- There are many pitfalls associated with setting variables from names given in function parameters.  This function avoids name clashes by using no additional local or global variables.  It avoids bad variable names by explicitly checking that variable names are correctly formed.  However, it will happily blow away your `PATH`, for instance, so it still needs to be used carefully.
- I've tested it with Bash 3.2 (released in 2006).  It won't work with older version of Bash because they didn't support `printf -v`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `printf`:

```
$ printf -v_ "%s%n" ":/path/to/a/directory" length
$ echo $length
21
```

`-v_ "%s"`to write the output to trash variable `_`

`"%n" "string" length` to write the length of the `string` to variable `length`.